# Electron Confusion about Security

Tags: javascript, security, electron

Ok, im just lost. I opened an electron start app and added one simple code, to console log on button press. The function is in a file renderer.js and in being called in in my index.html. Why when I press the button
I get this message ....

```
    Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content
 Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a
 hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Why would I not be allowed to execute something inline? An external source seems more vulnerable. Can anyone clear this up for me please?

Comment: Without your code, no one can see why that error might be about.

Answer (score 2):

Content Security Policy is using to avoid XSS based attacks in browser.In electron the background is running in a chrome engine, so the code is actullay running in a chromium browser.This browser is prone to all security issues that a browser is having

**What is Content-Security-Policy?**

Content-Security-Policy is the name of a HTTP response header that modern browsers use to enhance the security of the document (or web page). The Content-Security-Policy header allows you to restrict how resources such as JavaScript, CSS, or pretty much anything that the browser loads.

you can add the following code at the top of HTML to avoid the content security issue. this new header will allow the inline code to execute

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self';">
```

**What this meta tag will do ?**

*Allows*

With the above CSP policy, the following are allowed to load and execute in the browser:

```
<!-- allowed by 'self' -->
<script src="/js/some-file.js"></script>
<!-- allowed by https://js.example.com -->
<script src="https://js.example.com/file.js"></script>
```

*Blocks*

The Example Policy above will block the following from loading or executing in the browser:

```
<script src="https://attacker.example.com/file.js"></script>
```